# Is it possible to WebRTC Screen sharing from chrome without using extension?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, webrtc

We are able to share our screen with remote user using Mozilla quantum browser but not able to share screen using chrome browser. 
So can we share the screen with remote user without using any third party extensions on chrome?

Comment: as i know most browser screen sharing websites requires extensions. https://appear.in

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me how we can secure our extensions from being hacked? As we want to access the extension through only one domain.

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays it's possible!

```
let stream = null;
try {
  stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({ video: true, audio: true });
} catch(err) {
  console.warn("Error: " + err);
}
console.debug(stream);
```

Where `stream` is an instance of [MediaStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream) interface (just the same as you'd get it with `getUserMedia()`).

Answer (score 2):

No you can't.

Chrome places the extension as a prerequisite to be able to share your screen.